# Make the recommended tab available on a more permanent basis

Tags: feature-request, homepage, tabs, preferences

In the [Stack Exchange Podcast Episode 60](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-episode-60-are-we-that-predictable), at around the 27:30 mark, there was a mention of the "recommended tab" which currently does not have a UI for it.  Currently, the only way to get to it is to remember to add some options to the url.

e.g.,
https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended

Now I get that you guys don't want to change the homepage just yet for an experimental feature, but if it means getting the crappy questions off of my homepage and make it easier for me to view higher quality questions, I'm all for it.

The problem is, doing that isn't persistent.  Clicking on the "home icon" takes me to the "un-recommended" regular vanilla homepage.  It is terribly inaccessible.  My entire workflow for how I visit the sites revolve around how I access the homepages.

Please allow me to opt in to using this new tab without having to do url magic, extra GM scripting, one-time use bookmarks for a feature that will probably eventually be added.  Maybe make it available in the preferences somewhere?

[image: preferences section]

Comment: The stack overflow homepage is already a recommended page. Is this a different algorithm?

Comment: Yes. What was discussed in the podcast was that questions that were generally good and received answers fell off the homepage rather quickly because they were "done" while bad, generally unanswerable questions lingered around for too long often because they weren't. The recommended tab preserves those good questions a bit longer. Jump to ~24:15 of the podcast for more information.

Comment: @JanDvorak I hope you haven't been living under a rock and ended up missing this: [Feedback requested: New “recommended” homepage, phase 1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261138/456814).

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to make the Stack Exchange developers go through the work of implementing an opt-in preference for an experimental feature. [There are plans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261138/feedback-requested-new-recommended-homepage-phase-1) to eventually make this a permanent tab, perhaps even the default homepage tab for high-rep users.